# Send push through GCM to Android app setup with UrbanAirship

Tags: android, push, google-cloud-messaging, urbanairship.com

I have an application that is already setup with UrbanAirship and able to receive pushes. I am wondering if I can also send pushes directly to the device through the Google Cloud Message system that UrbanAirship uses?

You can use the UrbanAirship API to retrieve the GCM registration id associated with the device's APID.

Here is a sample response of what the GET APID call returns from the Urban API:

```
{
  "tags":  [
    "Tag1",
    "Tag2",
    "Tag3"
  ],
  "gcm_registration_id": "APA91bHgdRCTXZ-ZRXhnZ0krk30fjhehJoR4i3z9CsjNhUUc7w2KLA2ePX3cNcJiOLnYGpl8YP53BGHydqSTY5mfnX10enzmIOUPV8qClxtecpq5gqEcIt_ZJEnblVEnz41mHdmSUyV-MY_GCM_REGISTRATION_ID",
  "created": "2014-11-07 22:14:11",
  "alias": "",
  "apid": "df706e0f-0460-46dd-bc8f-4ac7e9dff758",
  "active": true,
  "last_registration": "2014-11-07 22:14:18"
}
```

From there I have tried to use the GCM registration id given to send a push directly to Google's GCM servers but UrbanAirship never builds a notification on the device.

I am posting a request to https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send with this body:

```
{
  "data": {
    "title": "Test Title",
    "message": "Test push "
  },
  "registration_ids": [
    "APA91bHgdRCTXZ-ZRXhnZ0krk30fjhehJoR4i3z9CsjNhUUc7w2KLA2ePX3cNcJiOLnYGpl8YP53BGHydqSTY5mfnX10enzmIOUPV8qClxtecpq5gqEcIt_ZJEnblVEnz41mHdmSUyV-MY_GCM_REGISTRATION_ID"
  ]
}
```

This post will work if I use my own implementation of GCM on the device with a IntentService and BroadcastReceiver. But every time I try to use this to send a push to my application with the UrbanAirship implementation it won't be delivered.

Comment: You need to send an API request to Urban Airship who then sends the notification on to GCM. http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/api/v3/push.html
https://dirigible.zendesk.com/entries/69805608-Helpful-cURL-Examples-for-API-v3

Comment: Sorry don't know if I was clear. I am trying to send a push without the Urban Airship API. I am wondering what Urban Airship sends to the GCM servers to get the push to be be recognized by their SDK on the device.

Comment: hey were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The param sent by UrbanAirship for the main alert message is `com.urbanairship.push.ALERT`, similar attributes handled by UrbanAirship Android SDK constants would have to be instantiated similarly.

You can use that with [uniqush-push](https://github.com/uniqush/uniqush-push) as such

```
curl http://localhost:9898/push -d "service=myapp_prod&subscriber=raffy&com.urbanairship.push.ALERT=you got an alert"
```

I am also working on a [ruby client](https://github.com/rafaelbandeira3/uniqush-rb).